# How can I make an NSStatusItem take the full height of the menubar?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nsstatusitem

I'd like to have an item in the macOS menubar that takes the whole height of the bar. This can be seen, for example, in FaceTime's UI:

[image]

In my attempts, I can only get the item to extend to 1pt away from the y edges of the menu bar:

[image]

(Note that in a menubar with a notch, even FaceTime won't extend to the edges, but it still extends 1pt further on the `top` and `bottom` than my versions).

I've tried both the `NSStatusItem` `button` and (deprecate) `view` to get things to work. I've also tried SwiftUI's `MenuBarExtra`

Simple example that leads to the second screenshot above:

```
final class StatusItemManager: ObservableObject {
    var statusButtonItem: NSStatusItem?
    var statusViewItem: NSStatusItem?
    
    /// Note that this uses deprecated APIs -- I'd prefer to stay away from these if possible
    func showViewStatusItem() {
        statusViewItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        
        guard let statusViewItem else { return }
        
        let iconView = NSHostingView(rootView: ItemView(title: "View"))
                
        statusViewItem.view = iconView
        
        statusViewItem.view?.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 40)
    }
    
    /// Non-deprecated, but still not working
    func showButtonStatusItem() {
        statusButtonItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        
        guard let statusButtonItem else { return }
        
        let iconView = NSHostingView(rootView: ItemView(title: "Button"))
        
        iconView.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 24)

        statusButtonItem.button?.addSubview(iconView)

        statusButtonItem.button?.action = #selector(menuBarButtonPressed)
        statusButtonItem.button?.target = self

        statusButtonItem.button?.frame = iconView.frame
    }
    
    struct ItemView: View {
        var title: String
        
        var body: some View {
            Text(title)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.green)
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func menuBarButtonPressed(_ sender: Any?) {
        print("pressed")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var manager = StatusItemManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            manager.showButtonStatusItem()
            manager.showViewStatusItem()
        }
    }
}
```